# Correct Curl command to upload local file from URL

Tags: php, curl

**Hi,I was provided with this code:**

```
<?php
$path = '/path/to/local/file';
$cFile = curl_file_create($path);
$token = '0123456789';
$post = array('token' => $token, 'file' => $cFile);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.myfiles.com/upload');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);
curl_close($ch);
if(isset($result['status']) && $result['status'] === 'success') {
echo $result['url'];
} else {
echo $result['message'];
}
?>
```

**This is the description:**

| Parameter | Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Endpoint | https://api.myfiles.com/upload | The API endpoint to which the request should be sent |
| token | 0123456789 | The authentication token required to authorize the request |
| file | Your file | The file you wish to upload |
| folder_alias (Optional) | Your folder alias (Optional) | The desired destination folder for the uploaded file |

My task is to use this data to upload files to the server using the command curl for Windows (CMD)

I'm using this code but it doesn't work:

```
curl --insecure -X POST https://api.myfiles.com/upload 'Authorization: Bearer 0123456789' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -F "file=@c:\myfiles\file.pdf"
```

Gives an error message:

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"token":["The token field is required."]}}
```

I will be glad for any help.

Comment: You can't upload a file with JSON content-type. It has to be `multipart/form-data`. `curl` will send that header automatically.

Comment: Is your question about the PHP code or the shell command? You're missing the token parameter in the shell command.

Comment: Add `-d token=0123456789 ` to the `curl` command.

Answer (score 0):

The token should be in the form data, not the `Authorization` header.

```
curl --insecure -X POST https://api.myfiles.com/upload -F 'token=0123456789' -F "file=@c:\myfiles\file.pdf"
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and it doesn't work again. {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"token":["The token field is required."]}} The main question is how to force the server to accept the token!

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation?

Comment: If the PHP code works, I'm pretty sure my code is equivalent, so I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: You can try this tool: https://github.com/ivastly/php2curl